# How to pick specific column from txt file with delimiters in c# Console application

Tags: c#

Hello I've got a data(in txt file) which contains 1,4 million rows ++ and i need to separate the data based on ID. So if in the data has 10 differents ID, then the console application will create 10 different files which each files contains data who has same ID.

My problem is , the data that have been given to me , not all columns to be insert, so if the data has has 10 columns, i only need to take 8 columns

Here's the code that i use to write and separate data into files with differents id

```
  string appPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
  string dirTxt = appPath + "VA_" + tglskrg;
  string dirZip = appPath + "VA_" + tglskrg + "\\ZIP";

 var writers = new Dictionary<string, TextWriter>();
            string header = "COMPANY CODE;CUSTOMER NUMBER;CUSTOMER NAME;INSERT DATE;TRANSACTION ID;TRANSACTION AMOUNT;ADMIN FEE;TRANSACTION REF;FLAG STATUS;TRANSACTION STATUS"; //its still 10 columns because my code still write all the columns in the old data .
            string inputFile = appPath + "va_txn_success_daily_"+tglkemarin+".txt";

            string outputPath = dirTxt;
            string outputPathh = dirZip;
            TextWriter writer;
            using (var reader = File.OpenText(inputFile))
            {
                //skip header
                reader.ReadLine();

                try
                {
                    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        //read one line and separate key and value
                        var line = reader.ReadLine();
                        var separatorIndex = line.IndexOf(';');
                        var id = line.Substring(0, separatorIndex);
                        var value = line.Substring(separatorIndex - 5);

                        //get a writer or create one
                        if (!writers.TryGetValue(id, out writer))
                        {
                            writer = File.CreateText(dirTxt + "\\" + "va_txn_success_" + id + "_" + tglskrg + ".txt");
                            writer.WriteLine(header);
                            writers.Add(id, writer);

                        }

                        //write the line to the correct file
                        writer.WriteLine(value);


                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    reader.Close();                    
                    //dispose all the writers
                    foreach (var writerr in writers.Values)
                    {
                        writerr.Dispose();
                    }
                }
```

I cant show the data , because the data its restricted

if i can give example so will be

```
COMPANY CODE;CUSTOMER NUMBER;CUSTOMER NAME;INSERT DATE;TRANSACTION ID;TRANSACTION AMOUNT;ADMIN FEE;TRANSACTION REF;FLAG STATUS;TRANSACTION STATUS;
A;01;Ricky;15-Jan;ABC01;1000;0;BCD123;Success;Trans success
B;02;John;15-Feb;ABC02;1500;1000;BCC122;Success;Trans success
A;02;Ricky;1-Jan;Abc03;2000;0;BCC;123;Success;Trans success
```

So it will be create 2 file , for A company Code and B company Code

And i want to take the company code, cust number, cust name, insert date, trans amount, trans ref, flag status ,and trans status only

Thankyou

Comment: So...there'll always be 10 fields, and they'll always be in the same order?

Comment: @Ben  in the old data yes it will be 10 fields and in the same order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the items of the line into an array. Easiest way: String.Split

```
string[] items = String.Split(";");
```

Then you are able to acces the columns;

```
string company = item[0};
string customer = item[1];
....
```